# Insert non-duplicate rows from one table to another mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables T1 and T2. I want to merge only those rows of T2 which is currently not there in T1 .

```
`Insert into T1 select * from (select * from T2 where id not in (select id from T1))`
```

Is there a better and faste way of achieving the same. ID column is unique across the table

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into T1 
select * from T2
where id not in (select id from T1)
```

You could also `join` but then you'd need another subselect since MySQL does not want to select from a table it inserts at the same time without using a subselect.

Comment: what if combination of two rows is the check instead of id ??

Comment: Then you need to join with a subselect.